# Font size on mobile is differenet on every sub-page, despite one size set for all

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

I'm going a bit mad here, I've set the font size to 1.05 rem across the website but when viewing each subpage on mobile (iPhone in my case) - each page shows different size. Any advice?

***Desktop view is FINE***

Distro page shows the paragraph in small font, whereas the catalog page quite large. They should be identical, I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong here.

Code below:

DISTRO page:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="copy">
    <p>I have a ton of tapes, CDs and records for sale. Will be listing them here in the coming days.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CATALOG page:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="copy">
    <p>Support the label and buy directly, message us via <b>daggerforest@gmail.com</b> and we can take it from there.</p><p>Alternatively our stock is also available on Bandcamp > <a href="https://daggerforest.bandcamp.com/" target"_blank"><b>daggerforest.bandcamp.com</b></a></p>

<div class="divider">✧</div>

<div class="cat-rel"><b>DF000</b> > <a href="https://daggerforest.bandcamp.com/album/dagger-forest" target="_blank">V.A.<span class="tab"></span>Dagger Forest</a><br><span class="descr">
CDR / 20 copies / 「12.07.2014」</span></div>
<div class="cat-rel"><b>DF001</b> >  <a href="https://daggerforest.bandcamp.com/album/when-you-burn" target="_blank">Daan Mol<span class="tab"></span>When You Burn</a><br><span class="descr">
C12 / 50 copies / 「09.10.2014」</span></div>
<div class="cat-rel"><b>DF002</b> >  <a href="https://daggerforest.bandcamp.com/album/ep1" target="_blank">E Y E S H A D O W S<span class="tab"></span>EP1</a><br><span class="descr">
C17 / 50 copies / 「05.02.2015」</span></div>
<div class="cat-rel"><b>DF003</b> >  <a href="https://daggerforest.bandcamp.com/album/heru-ra-ha" target="_blank">Mascara<span class="tab"></span>Heru-Ra-Ha</a><br><span class="descr">
C22 / 50 copies / 「29.07.2015」</span></div>
<div class="divider">✧</div>
  <p><div  class="middle"><img src="https://witch-house.com/tape.jpg" class="banner-sm"></img></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Syne Mono", monospace;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left:  10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;}

a:hover {color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;}
    
.middle {   text-align: center;
}

.copy  {width:100%;
    max-width:780px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
}

.divider {  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
.tab {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
.descr {font-size:1rem;}

.cat-rel {margin-bottom:20px;}
```

Comment: Have you added meta tag of viewport? Try this in your head tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: @anoncephal omg this is so embarassing, yes! thank you

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552)

Answer (score 0):

The `rem` unit refers to the `font-size` setting for `html`, and if that isn't defined in the styesheet, it refers to the default size of the browser (which *can* be changed in the browser settings, but that's not done very often)

The `em` unit refers to the default `font-size` of the current element (div, p, h1, h2, h3, li etc.), also something that *can* be defined by the programmer, but if it's not, it's defined in the browser default settings.

So although you define a `font-size` for `body`, you didn't for `html`, which most likely causes the differences you see.

Try to define the `font-size` for `html`, I'm sure the result will at least be better than with your current settings.